Install TP-Link Archer T2U V3 driver in Ubuntu without internet
I'm using archer T2U v3 in my 14.04 and 16.04 system flawlessly as the driver was directly provided by TP-Link from their website https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/archer-t2u/#Driver (Kernel version 2.6.18~5.0)

According to their PDF link https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201812/20181207/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf I just had to use make command to compile their driver and load it by  sudo insmod 88x2bu.ko.
Recently I upgraded my system and found that direct make command don't work from Ubuntu 18.04 onward as it says make should be installed first.
So I researched and have already gone through these links like TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04 or Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10 where I'll have to execute these commands
sudo apt install git dkms 
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git 
cd rtl8812au 
sudo make dkms_install 

but there is a problem as I cannot access internet directly even by usb tethering due to some problem so my question is can I some how install those packages like dkms git build-essential from another working machine to this machine? Can I install those packages in offline mode?
Thanks in advance

Are you currently using a supported version of Ubuntu and are you trying to say that archer T2U v3 worked flawlessly on 14.04 and 16.04 and that you need to install it on a newer version of Ubuntu?

No questions asked and end of standard support releases.

@mikewhatever my browser closed unexpectedly so I've to edit it again :P

Please try Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04. If the issue exists, ask a new question.

Address the tethering problem first?

@ArchismanPanigrahi yes the problem starts from 18.04 onward as there I can't run the make  command, but what is interesting is that according to TP-Link website their driver should work on from kernel 2.6-5.0 but it fails to run make command  from 18.04 as make isn't installed it says where as in 14.04 0r 16.04 make works flawlessly

@waltinator as I told earlier I can't enable tethering as here I'm not allowed to use mobile devices

Then you will have to download the .deb file of make https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/make/download in another computer, and install it using USB drive. To install a .deb package use the command sudo apt install ./path/to/package.deb

@ArchismanPanigrahi what I've found till now that is the only solution so I've kept it as last ditch effort but I was trying to find if any other ways also exists, btw can you confirm me that if build-essential or make is preinstalled from 18.04 onwards or not?

@A.Bhowmick I don't know because I don't have a new installation to test with.

It might be simpler to return the dongle and purchase one that really is compatible. Downloading and manually installing a "driver" has NOT been considered "compatible" for over a decade. Real compatibility means the code has been contributed to the kernel upstream, and your device is plug-and-play without you installing anything. Don't give your money to a vendor that lied to you.

If you have another working machine, consider running a VM with "multipass" that allows you to build whatever you need, and then copy it to the machine in question.  Alternatively borrow a supported netcard/wifi and install what you need before returning it.

"as here I'm not allowed to use mobile devices" ... why not?   If there are company policies in place, you may to double check to ensure that your usage of Linux is complient.

I did this a few years ago. It's an iterative process. Requirements: A USB key; A working Ubuntu system, (call it hq), and the target system (tgt). You can use a non-Ubuntu hq, but downloading the .deb files to the USB key is up to you.

On hq, use apt-get --download-only install on your list of packages.
On hq copy the .deb files you downloaded in Step 1 to the USB key.
sudo eject the USB key, and move it to tgt.
On tgt, cd to the USB key, and sudo dpkg -i *.deb 2>err.log to try to install the packages. Some (many, all) may fail due to "dependencies". The error messages will be saved in err.log.
On tgt, cd back to $HOME, sudo eject the USB key, and move it back to hq.
On hq, inspect err.log, extract the package names, add them to your list of packages, and go back to Step 1.
Eventually, 3 or 4 iterations, err.log will have no errors, and you are done! After 10+ iterations, with continuing errors, you have entered "dependency hell", and must rethink/redesign your process.

When program/Package A needs to use Program/Package B for something, A is dependent on B. These "dependencies" are what the above is resolving.

will try your process ASAP but I've two more question and that is according to https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au we have to install linux-headers but in this forum its not been mentioned and secondly why the make command is working out of the box in 14.04 and 16.04 where as from 18.04 its not working?

AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have new information on your original question, [edit] the question and add it. If you have a new question, [ask] it. Do not try to start conversations in a Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

@waltinator Then what do we have chat rooms for?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen presumably to keep the extended conversations out of the main QA site?
